# react-hook-form validation on form post without XHR

Tags: reactjs, forms, xmlhttprequest, react-hook-form

I have a form that uses [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com) for validation and I want to post the form on submit but not using an XHR request, i.e. I want to use an actual post request, not using JavaScript.

The problem is that it does not appear I can have both. If I include `onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}` then the validation works but I don't know how to actually post the form (not via XHR) using the `onSubmit`, and if I remove the `onSubmit` then the form posts as expected but the validation no longer kicks in :(

Hoping someone out there may have come across the same thing before. Many thanks in advance.